# How to use the Charts module for creating charts using Views?

Tags: views, 6, charts

I am using Drupal 6 and trying to setup the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module to work with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

On the Charts project pages it says

> **Views integration**: Display the Views results as charts

so views is supported. However I had no luck at all so far. Even though the module seems very well written, it lacks documentation.

**My question**: How to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I used (running a brand new drupal 6.25 install):

- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) 6.x-2.16
- [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) 6.x-1.3 (required for Charts)
- [Charts](http://drupal.org/project/charts) 6.x-1.0

The Charts module comes with a few chart providers (SD Image Chart and Google Charts). You need to enable one of them in the module list to use in views. I enabled Google Charts for this example.

Then, I created a new view. I set the Style option to "Chart". To demo the chart, I just added a Node: Nid field and created some dummy nodes. The chart provider you selected will  render the chart in the preview for you. You can configure the Style Plugin settings and the fields to get the kind of chart you want.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it I couldn't figure out the 'style' part. I actually looked it up when I was trying to set it up last night but I guess we shouldn't be fighting sleep and working at the same time, right? :) Thank you!!